# First day at work in Canada

Tags: company-culture, offices, first-job, canada

I just came to Vancouver (BC, Canada) from Europe and tomorrow is my first day at work in a small IT company (~15-20 people).

So I have a few questions about common manners at work in Canada.

When you come in for a new day of work and see coworkers, is it common to come to everyone's desk and shake hands, or just say "Hi" or "Good morning"? Also, is it common to come to boss office and just stop on the doorway (if his office doors are open) and say "Good morning"?

Previously I've worked in Europe, also in a small IT company. It was common to shake hands with male co-workers every morning and say "Good morning" to the boss on the doorstep at his office or shaking hands if met in other room.

Also what good tips do you have for my first day at work? Especially, what is common in Canada? I'm an introvert, usually I don't like interact to much with other people and tomorrow will be very stressful day for me..

Comment: I would add that it's important to treat men and women the same. If you treat them differently (handshake vs good morning) you could actually be perceived as sexist or at the very least, insecure.

Comment: To be fair, it's really common for American men to avoid shaking women's hands as well. The good news is that other men seldom notice this, and usually people in authority are men. So you're unlikely to be penalized for this subtle sexism unless you're unwise enough to say publicly that you do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Welcome to Canada!

Shaking hands is normal the first day. Not every day.

Good morning is normal if you work in the same office or space but could be seen as interrupting or distracting if they're in their own office.

Going out for lunch if offered is a good bet if you want to get to know people. Turning it down could be seen as rude anyways.